# Opening Visual studio 2012

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Have installed Visual Studio 2012 Trial, but it doesn't add any icons to the desktop.

So how can I open it and then add the icons to the desktop in Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> opens the search menu, type here "visual " and you should see an icon of VS 2012 - start it. During the program runs you can always add the icon to task bar or whatever ...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by 'Trial', you mean the Visual Studio Express version, go to the start screen, and type 'VS'.  You should see a 'VS Express' show up in the search results for applications.

Answer (score 0):

I do not has installed MSVC 2012 but have MSVC 2010. I think 2012 has analogue path to start application :

```
%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Comment: MSVC has almost the same path just "Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" instead of "Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" :)